# Move the button randomly on the screen without click

Tags: android, button, random, click

I want to get a button to move randomly around the screen without having to implement an `onClick` method to move it. I am using `Random` with `setX` and `setY` to set the buttons attributes for a different activity that works great, but I want the button to move on its own using the same `setX` and `setY` randomly. Any ideas or what is a good method to use for this?

Comment: Use a thread with a handler

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add this code in your `onCreate()` :

```
Thread t = new Thread() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    while (!isInterrupted()) {
                        Thread.sleep(1000);
                        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                              // Your logic for setting your button 
                              // randomly on the screen
                            }
                        });
                    }
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                }
            }
        };
        t.start();
```

Comment: Suggest `Thread.sleep(900 + rand.nextInt(200));` or similar to vary the time between jumps.

Comment: @rossum I'm trying to implement that currently, that is a very good idea! Thanks as well!